# How to select recursively select rows from a table matching a certain criteria

Tags: mysql

We have a Mysql table user_documents. This table maps document with a user.

**Data Definition of the table**

1. id - primary key of the table
2. document_id - foreign key to the document table
3. user_id - foreign key to the user table.
4. hierarchy_order - order of hierarchy.

**Sample table data**

```
| id | document_id | user_id | hierarchy_order |
| 1  | 1           | 1       | 1               |
| 2  | 1           | 2       | 2               |
| 3  | 1           | 3       | 3               |
| 4  | 1           | 4       | 4               |
| 5  | 2           | 1       | 1               |
| 6  | 2           | 3       | 2               |
| 7  | 2           | 2       | 3               |
| 8  | 2           | 4       | 4               |
| 9  | 3           | 2       | 1               |
| 10 | 3           | 1       | 2               |
| 11 | 3           | 3       | 3               |
| 12 | 3           | 4       | 4               |
| 13 | 4           | 1       | 1               |
| 14 | 4           | 3       | 2               |
| 15 | 4           | 4       | 3               |
| 16 | 4           | 2       | 4               |
```

We have a hierarchy table list the user in a simple hierarchy. This table is changed frequently and order of users gets changed.

We cannot rely on the hierarchy table as it changes frequently. Hence we are logging the document_id with user_id and what hierarchy order that user was.

For the document_id = 1 in the user_documents table, the hierarchy was.

- level 1 (top level) - user_id - 1
- level 2 - user_id - 2
- level 3 - user_id - 3
- level 4 - user_id - 4

**Problem Statement**

We want to select all records/rows for user_id 2 and other users where their hierarchy order is greater than or equal to user_id 2 hierarchy_order for all document_id.

Expected output

```
| id | document_id | user_id | hierarchy_order |
| 2  | 1           | 2       | 2               |
| 3  | 1           | 3       | 3               |
| 4  | 1           | 4       | 4               |


| 7  | 2           | 2       | 3               |
| 8  | 2           | 4       | 4               |

| 9  | 3           | 2       | 1               |
| 10 | 3           | 1       | 2               |
| 11 | 3           | 3       | 3               |
| 12 | 3           | 4       | 4               |


| 16 | 4           | 2       | 4               |
```

We are using MySQL Database and not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you research this before posting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - updated the description, new to StackOverflow ran into formatting issues. But yeah, I have been researching this issue for last few days.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL version: 5.7.25